# Git : cannot push because 2 empty URLs in config

Tags: git

I am a beginner in Git
I get this strange behavior :

1 / When i push some code, Git says '=' is not an URL !!

```
git push -u origin master
---> fatal: '=' does not appear to be a git repository
```

2 / So i check the config, and i see 2 "push" URLs are equal to "="

```
git config --list
---> ... 
remote.origin.url== 
remote.origin.url== 
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:<name>/<project>.git (push)
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

How can i correct that error ???
the.git/config file seems to be normal

Comment: Those are, technically, *fetch* URLs rather than (or in addition to) push URLs. However, there should normally only be one URL, or at most two URLs, for any given repository. The extra ones you show here are not empty: they are set to the equal sign `=`. Delete the wrong ones from whichever files they appear in, as in [1615903's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247478/1256452).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `git config --list --show-origin` to determine where the empty values come from, output will be something like this:

```
file:.git/config                remote.origin.url== 
file:/other/directory/config    remote.origin.url==
```

Then remove the config lines from those files.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.git/config` to remove two blank URLs.

```
[remote "origin"] // Search this section.
```

**Notice**: `.git` is a hidden folder in your project root directory.

Comment: Thanks, but this file seems to be ok ;[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:ericdumond/OpenClassroomProject.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*