# how to delete user.name and user.email that empty in git

Tags: git

I entered the wrong user.name and user.email. and now `git config -l` looks like this:
[image]

i've try `git config --global --unset user. email` and `git config --global --unset user. name` but it wont dissaper. how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git : cannot push because 2 empty URLs in config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246421/git-cannot-push-because-2-empty-urls-in-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git config --show-origin --list` to find where those configs from. This will give you the important information about how to remove it precisely.

They maybe NOT from `global`.

Something not important: They are not "empty", they seems having a value of `=`.

Comment: it comes like this : file:.git/config where is it?

Comment: i've reseach and i found its from local. thankyou for the solutions

Answer (score 1):

That config is set in your current repository, not globally. As such, you should not use `--global` when unsetting. Additionally, since you have them set multiple times, you'll have to use `--unset-all`:

```
git config --unset-all user.name
git config --unset-all user.email
```